# How can i get a better result Baking in blender render?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, baking, unity

I have a little question here, it is possible improve the result of the baking in this model (Blender Render)?

In the image We can see a little deffects like black points ,can i improve that?
[image]

Edit and Solution:

Just need to increase the samples in the World tab , i increase the value to 25:

[image]

And here the final result Thanks for everyone!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance I would think that noise is due to a low sample setting.

You might try to increase the gathering samples.
Go  into the "Scene Settings" in the "Properties Editor", under "Gather", if you set it to use raytracing, you can change the sample settings.

But yeah, just a guess into the wild, maybe I am wrong? Hard to say without having the scene open...

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the answer :D But i think that you mean in the cycles render, in the cycles render i see the sampling window but in blender render doesen't appear.

Comment: Sry, updated my answer...

Comment: I solved now thanks , i posted how i made it if you have some doubts :D

Comment: Glad I was able to help, you may want to mark the question as answered if the problem is solved. Have a nice day! :)